# check given answer answer if match random quest

Tags: php

Hi I am using this code to generate random question:

```
<?php
session_start(); //this was missing from this file
//connect to db
require_once('db_conn.php');

$id=rand(0,13); //2nd number = highest ID

if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT quest FROM table WHERE ID='$id'")){

   $resQ = $res->fetch_assoc(); 
   echo "" . $resQ['quest'] . "";

   $_SESSION['chckanswer'] = $resQ['guest'];

   $res->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

and this one to try and check if answer given match the question:

```
<?php
session_start();

//more code

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT quest FROM table WHERE answer=?')){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['given_answer']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($quest);
    $stmt->fetch();

        if($_SESSION['chckanswer'] != $quest && !empty($_SESSION['chckanswer'])){
        echo 'wrong';
        exit();
        }
        else{
        echo 'ok';
        }
    $stmt->close();    
}
//more code
```

But I get error **undifined index chckanswer**

Comment: Have you called session_start(); in the file that you are getting the error in?

Comment: @DanPrince, damn 1 sec before me.

Comment: For the love of Mike, please use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 instead of $id=rand(0,13); If you add a question you'll have to change your hard coded 13 to 14!

Comment: Yes I get the error on the 2nd file and I have session_start. But I do not have it in my first file. Now, if I add it at the first as well, I get **Headers already sent** error

Comment: do it at the top of the script before anything else

Comment: @waygood I always have it at the top of the script...

Comment: Ok, check what is present by way of session variables by doing:
`echo(json_encode($_SESSION));`
You should get a JSON string representation of your array and you can check whether your session has been started and whether the element that you are expecting is there.

Comment: @DanPrince at which file do I put the echo?

Comment: The file in which you are trying to get the value inside $_SESSION['chckanswer']

Comment: @DanPrince I did it but I get the same result

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean you get the same result? This isn't supposed to fix the error, you need to check what is being printed out.

Comment: @DanPrince I know is not a fix... but I got nothing different.

Comment: Is nothing being printed out? If so is the error happening before you get to your echo statement? If not then it looks like your session hasn't started correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was missing from the 1st file:

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=rand(0,13); // 0-13
```

I don't think there is no row with id "zero"

```
isset($_SESSION['chckanswer']) ? $_SESSION['chckanswer'] : null;
```

add this line